# how can I combine first-of-type, first-line, and first-letter pseudo elements?

Tags: html, css

currently, i am working on an assignment for web development course.

these are the instructions: 
First Line and Drop Cap Styles
Jakob wants the first line from the article to be displayed in small capital letters. Go to the First Line and Drop Cap Styles section and create a style rule for the first paragraph of the article element and the first line of that paragraph, setting the font size to 1.25em and the font variant to small-caps. (Hint: Use the first-of-type pseudo-class for the paragraph and the first-line pseudo-element for the first line of that paragraph.)

Jakob also wants the first letter of the first line in the article’s opening paragraph to be displayed as a drop cap. Create a style rule for the article’s first paragraph and first letter that applies the following styles:
sets the size of the first letter to 4em in a serif font and floats it on the left,
sets the line height to 0.8em, and
sets the right and bottom margins to 5 pixels.
(Hint: Use the first-letter pseudo-element for the first letter of that paragraph.)

this is the code that i've put:

```
 /* First Line and Drop Cap Styles */

    p:first-of-type:first-line {
      font-size: 1.25em;
      font-variant: small-caps;
    }

    p:first-letter {
      font-size: 4em;
      line-height: 0.8em;
      margin-right: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
```

I get it to work since I get error message over and over. I need help on this.

thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
p:first-of-type, p:first-line {
  //styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
article p:first-of-type::first-line { 
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}

article p:first-of-type::first-letter {
    font-size: 4em;
    font-family: serif;
    float: left;
    line-height: 0.8em;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: It would help the quality of your contribution if you would use the [edit] link under the question to add an explanation *why* the code you propose answers the question.